# How to put text with headings on clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net

If I copy text (using the cursor etc. I don't mean programmatically) from a web page or Word document, and paste it in a Word document - Word knows what text is a heading, and what is simple text. I want to do the same thing (programmatically) - put text on the clipboard and specify that part of it is heading1, part heading2... and part is simple text.

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx) class to put html text (which can have headings) on the clipboard, but was wondering:
a) That's from January 2007. Perhaps there's a simpler way now.
b) HTML only allows up to 6 heading levels. (I actually tried h7 but Word didn't recognize it.) Perhaps there's some way to have unlimited heading levels like Word does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the clipboard Handling had updates in the latest versions of .net framework.
I think that more complex updates/adding content to a word document may be achieved using ole automation or the open xml sdk.